# DateTimePicker with ShowUpDown control doesn't increase year with months

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm using the standard DateTimePicker in windows forms with a custom format of `yyyyMM` (the day is not relevant) and the `ShowUpDown` property set to true.

Using the up arrow to increase the month allows me to increase it from 12 to 1 (December to January) but doesn't increase the year.
So the value in my DateTimePicker goes from `201812` to `201801` while I would expect it to show `201901`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's nothing out of the box to achieve this behavior. So, here's a workaround, it's a bit hacky but it works:

```
private DateTime LastDate;
private void dtPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime newDate = dtPicker.Value;
    if (newDate.Year == LastDate.Year)
    {
        if (LastDate.Month == 12 && newDate.Month == 1)
            dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.Value.AddYears(1);
        else if (LastDate.Month == 1 && newDate.Month == 12)
            dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.Value.AddYears(-1);
    }

    LastDate = dtPicker.Value;
}
```

Since you have the `ShowUpDown` property set to true, the user will not be able to change the value in any other way. The only downside I can think of is when you change the value in your code, for example, if the current value is `201812` and you try to set it to `201801`, you'll get `201901` instead. To prevent this from happening, you can remove the event handler before changing the value, and then re-add it right after:

```
dtPicker.ValueChanged -= dtPicker_ValueChanged;
dtPicker.Value = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);
dtPicker.ValueChanged += dtPicker_ValueChanged;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I'll mark it as my accepted answer if nobody else can do it better in the next hour or so.