# DateTimePicker with ShowUpDown property doesn't increase year with months

Tags: c#, winforms

When using DateTimePicker with ShowUpDown property we are able to modify values of date by using "arrows" or but manually entering values. But one functionality which I wanted was when I am rotating through months that when you "going up" from 12 to 1, it will also increase year, and vice versa.

So I wrote small code for that which I found, because someone had similar problem:
[DateTimePicker with ShowUpDown control doesn't increase year with months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52077177/datetimepicker-with-showupdown-control-doesnt-increase-year-with-months)

```
private DateTime LastDate;
private void dtPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime newDate = dtPicker.Value;
    if (newDate.Year == LastDate.Year)
    {
        if (LastDate.Month == 12 && newDate.Month == 1)
            dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.Value.AddYears(1);
        else if (LastDate.Month == 1 && newDate.Month == 12)
            dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.Value.AddYears(-1);
    }

    LastDate = dtPicker.Value;
}
```

So the problem with that is that when we are manually changing value in combo box it is also changing that value so for example if I have
2000/12/01
and all I wanted is to change month to 01, then it will also change year to 2001.

So I was wandering if there is any way I can recognize if value was set using keyboard or using "arrows"?

Comment: You have a DateTime object.  So just AddMonths(1) which will automatically roll over the month and year.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dtPicker.PreviewKeyDown += this.dtPicker_PreviewKeyDown;
    dtPicker.ValueChanged += this.dtPicker_ValueChanged;
}

private DateTime LastDate;
private bool skipNextChange = false;

private void dtPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (skipNextChange) { skipNextChange = false; return; }
    DateTime newDate = dtPicker.Value;
    if (newDate.Year == LastDate.Year)
    {
        if (LastDate.Month == 12 && newDate.Month == 1)
            dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.Value.AddYears(1);
        else if (LastDate.Month == 1 && newDate.Month == 12)
            dtPicker.Value = dtPicker.Value.AddYears(-1);
    }

    LastDate = dtPicker.Value;
}

private void dtPicker_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    skipNextChange = true;
}
```

Add logic to handle keyboard input to skip the next value changed event.
**Note:** this is a super basic example to get you started. This will prevent the value changed event logic on all keyboard input. Ideally you need to flesh it out to probably only skip keyboard when 0 thru 9 keys and the slash (or divider character - depending on date format) are inputted. As the basic example is now, if you hit the up/down keyboard keys, it functions like hitting the up/down UI buttons, but because all keyboard input suppresses the value changed event, the up/down keyboard input would cycle just the month and not the year.

I'm not sure if you are aware of this, but the up/down buttons on the Day portion of the date do not cycle the month, so your current behavior is inconsistent. IE, if the date is '2000/12/31', and you cycle up on the Day value, it currently changes to '2000/12/01'. If you want to be consistent, it should roll to '2001/01/01'.

An alternative to all this you have 3 options:

1. Find an existing control that has the behavior you want. There are products (not usually free) that replace some of the default WinForms controls with more robust / more customizable versions.
2. Build your own either as a custom control class or a UserControl.
3. Use a hosted WPF DatePicker control that you've customized.

There are things I love and hate about WPF, but in this regard, the pure customization you can achieve in WPF controls might be a better fit for what you are hoping to accomplish.